# FFmpeg recording audio from several sources

Tags: windows, audio, video, ffmpeg, directshow

everyone.
I'm trying to use FFmpeg to record video and 3 audio sources and use it to generate 3 different video files - each file should contain the same video stream but the different audio stream. The problem is that I got audio sync issues. The first audio stream is synced perfectly, but the second one has 1 sec lag, and the third one has like 2 sec lag.

I've made a few tests so far and it seems that root cause of the issue is initialization time of video/audio devices. So, one device is already recording something but the second is still being opened and so on. I've tried to change input devices order and after that audio streams still have the same issue BUT if before 2nd and 3rd audio streams were some time ahead of video, after reordering they became to lag after the audio (audio for the same event appears with some delay). So this test confirms my version about device initialization times.

But the question still, why the first audio stream is synchronized properly, while other 2 are not. and also, how could I overcome this issues? Any workarounds and ideas are highly appreciated.

Here is FFmpeg command I'm using and it's output.

> ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -i video="Logitech HD Webcam
>   C615"  -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (HD Webcam C615)" -f dshow -i
>   audio="Microphone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio)"
>   -filter_complex "[1:a]volume=1[a1];[2:a]volume=1[a2]" -vf scale=h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -vcodec libx264
>   -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -preset ultrafast -acodec aac -vbr 5 -threads 0 -map v:0 -map [a1] -map [a2] -f tee
>   "[select=\'v,a:0\']C:/Users/vshevchu/Desktop/123/111/111_jjj1.avi|
>   [select=\'v,a:1\']C:/Users/vshevchu/Desktop/123/111/111_jjj2.avi"

[OUTPUT](https://pastebin.com/A3FL05My)

PS. Actually, the issue is exactly the same when I'm not using "tee" muxer but writing all the audio streams to one container. So, "tee" isn't a suspect.

Comment: What happens if you start three separate ffmpeg processes?

Comment: I run these processes from C++ and I've also tried run them as separate ones. In that case, I also get unsynced streams cause I can't start all of them precisely at the same time. As far as I understand, video recording process takes more time to start than audio one. So this is not a good solution too. I believe there should be a way to get the perfectly synced audio streams. I probably just miss some obvious detail.